# lru_cache и очистка кэша

Tags: python, кэширование

Есть телеграм бот, который по расписанию отправляет цитаты. Добавил к одной из его функций кэширование через `lru_cache` модуля `functools`.

В итоге пользователям 3 раза (в разное время) пришли одинаковые цитаты, хотя `cache_clear()` у меня стоит после каждой рассылки. Цитаты берутся из MongoDB, и как раз этот момент я хочу закешировать, чтобы на него не уходило по целой секунде.

```
class Quote:
    @lru_cache(maxsize=19)
    def check(self, user: str, check=True) -> dict:
        """Checks for quote available for {user}"""
        est_quotes = self.db.estimated_document_count()
        if self.db.count_documents({"Users": user}) >= est_quotes - 1:
            # removes user id from DB if there is no more available quotes for user
            self.db.update_many({"Users": user}, {"$pull": {"Users": user}})
        all_quotes = self.db.find({})
        while True:
            quote = all_quotes[random.randint(0, est_quotes - 1)]
            if not check:
                # if check for available is not required return random quote
                return quote
            if user in quote["Users"]:
                continue
            required_quote = quote
            self.db.update_one({"Quote": quote["Quote"]}, {"$push": {"Users": user}})
            return required_quote

    def random(self, user, checking=False):
        """ Sends random quote for user.
            If checking == False, it does not check for the presence of id in the database.
        """
        quo = self.check(user, check=checking)
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key_book = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='', callback_data='book', url=quo["URL"])
        keyboard.add(key_book)
        #   key_like = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='no')
        #   keyboard.add(key_like)
        bot.send_message(user,
                         text=f'<i>{quo["Quote"]}\n</i>\n<b>{quo["Book"]}</b>\n#{quo["Author"]}',
                         parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=keyboard)

    def randoms(self, group: int):
        """Sends random quote for users who aren't in 'stopped' list"""
        start_time = time.time()
        counter = 0
        with open(f'users{group}', 'r') as users_r:
            r = users_r.read().splitlines()
        print("=================================")
        for user_id in r:
            if user_id in self.stopped:
                continue
            try:
                self.random(str(user_id), True)
                print(f"Latency #{counter}: {str(time.time() - start_time)[:4]} seconds")
            except telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException as e:
                print(f"Bad ID ({user_id}):", e)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            finally:
                counter += 1
        self.check.cache_clear()
```

Скорее всего я просто много не понимаю о том как и что кэшируется, но прошу подсказать оптимальное решение моей проблемы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смысл работы [кеширующих декораторов из `functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) как раз в том, чтобы возвращать одинаковые результаты из кеша **при вызове декорируемой функции с одинаковыми аргументами**.

Т.е. в вашем случае, если мы вызовем метод `.check(user="user1")` 18 раз подряд с одним и тем же значением аргумента `user`, то мы 18 раз получим **одинаковый** результат.

По-моему это явно идет вразрез с вашими намерениями и `lru_cache` это неправильный инструмент в вашем случае.

PS обычно кеширующие декораторы используют для [детерминированных функций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), но не для тех, которые возвращают случайный результат.